# What kind of hash/encryption is this? '0E0B020601'

Tags: php, security, asp-classic, hex

I've been asked to design back-end in php for a web app having ASP front-end. So I can't really dig up those ASP files. I have the MySQL database - that's it! The programmer who made the front-end isn't responding.

How do I decode this? Or just this - "what's the name of this encryption method?"

It looks something like HEX though.

Another sample - 0E0800160E0330595D57

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0E 0B 02 06 01
0E 08 00 16 0E 03 30 59 5D 57
```

UPDATE - When I change my password to "kachwa" (without quotes), it gets updated as `040E0C07180E` in the database.

Comment: "What kind of encryption is this? 0xLOLOLOLOLOL - looks like Hax to me"

Comment: This is no troll people.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: You realize plenty of encryption and hash algorithms out there actually output hexadecimal strings, right?

Comment: @BoltClock: I would guess _every_ hash is representable as hex, thats the problem. Its like saying "which currency is 123?" It can be everything.

Comment: @BotClock Not sure. I know little about this windows' stuff. Think it's asp.net

Comment: Yes, that could be hex.  But there are a very large number (as in, "pretty much all of them") of hash and encryption algorithms that produce an output that can be expressed as an 80-bit hexadecimal number.  You're really not providing enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @KPL: How long is each hex string you see?

Comment: @BoltClock The largest is 30.

Comment: @KPL If you change a user's password to "1234", what does the hashed password look like?

Comment: Please add that long one an probably some other ones with different length to the question. This needs to be reverse engineered so a bit more info is always useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each byte is xor'd with 0x6f.

PHP sample encryption:

```
function enc($pass)
{
  $enc = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($pass); ++$i)
    $enc .= sprintf("%02x", ord($pass[$i]) ^ 0x6f);

  return $enc;
}

echo enc("kachwa"),"\n";
```

Output:

```
040e0c07180e
```

And for the sake of completeness:

```
function dec($pass)
{
  $dec = '';
  foreach (str_split($pass, 2) as $hex)
    $dec .= chr(hexdec($hex) ^ 0x6f);
  return $dec;
}

echo dec("040e0c07180e"),"\n";
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was going to be something like that (just intuition, I guess, "XOR" was floating through my head when I read the question.) Ouch. Well worked out. And @KPL, if this thing is anywhere near the public internet, consider switching it to a *good* password-hashing algorithm.

Comment: @Matt Right. Gotta convert all those to double-MD5 (salted).

Comment: @KPL On the plus side, you'll be able to retrieve the original passwords to convert them easily as a batch :) Much easier than moving from one good hashing system to another one!

Comment: @KPL, using PHP's `crypt` with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` or `CRYPT_SHA512` with many rounds will generate the best type of password hashing.